# How to make Firebase Database query faster on iOS Application?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, gif

I'm using Firebase Database to query gif posts to my application. These posts take a lot of time to load on the app in a collection view. I'm not clear if the problem is in the application or the database.

```
POSTS_REF.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 9).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {  [weak self] (snapshot) in
                self?.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

                guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
                guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
                allObjects.map({(snapshot) in
                    let postId = snapshot.key
                self?.fetchPost(withPostId: postId)

                })
                self?.currentKey = first.key
            })
```

```
func fetchPost(withPostId postId: String) {
        Database.fetchPost(with: postId) { (post) in
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                return post1.creationDate > post2.creationDate
            })
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing useful we can say here without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem, and probably some output showing timing. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I added the code of fetching the gif posts.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good first step. The time it takes to read data from Firebase is primarily a function of the amount of data you read and the bandwidth/latency of the device you read it on. So: how much data is in those 9 child nodes, what bandwidth does it have, and how long did what operation take? Also, the `self?.fetchPost(withPostId: postId)` seems like it might matter to the performance, but we can't see what it does.

Comment: I added the self.fetchPost(withPostId: postId) code. Those child node contains the url to the gif post in the Firebase Storage and username of the author of the post.

Comment: There's just not enough we can say/do with what you've shared so far. Please read the link I posted earlier and imagine how you can make it easier for us to help you. I'll gladly open xcode, and add a snippet of code you provide to a test project, and then run that. But if I need to take more steps, that reduces the chances that I'll do them, or do them correctly. So: please show the actual data, the minimal code without external dependencies, and the actual performance numbers you get (e.g. by logging with timers) in your question.

Comment: You can test your code with Instruments (Command-I in Xcode) to find bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `field` that you are using for the query to the Realtime Database rules.

For example, the `userName` field is the key of `user` table.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null",
    "v1": {
            "user": {
                ".indexOn": "userName"
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

You can use array for `.indexOn` field like `".indexOn": ["userName", "createdAt"]`